# how to load data from a .dat file into a table using cql

Tags: cassandra

I try to load data from a .dat file into my table using cql. I can only find the commend to read from csv file in documentation, so tried that kind of commend but all get error:

```
copy users (uid, gender, age, occu, zip) from ('/cassandra-input/users.dat') with delimiter = ':';
Improper copy command.

copy users (uid, gender, age, occu, zip) from ('/cassandra-input/users.dat' | stdin) with delimiter = ':';
    Invalid syntax at line 1, char 77
      copy users (uid, gender, age, occu, zip) from ('/cassandra-input/users.dat' | stdin) with delimiter = ':';

  copy users from '/cassandra-input/users.dat' with delimiter = ':';
Not in any keyspace.
```

so is there any one who can help me to figure out how to do this loading job.

Comment: is there a 'users' table created?

Comment: @Chrislohfink of course, I have created that table.

Comment: Without knowing what the `.dat` file looks like, I can't really speak to `COPY`'s ability to parse it.  But I can tell you that there are no parens around the file location on `COPY`.  Get rid of the parens, and see if/what error it gives you.

Comment: `Not in any keyspace.` that is happening because you need to switch to which ever keyspace contains the `users` table.  Or you can preface the table with the keyspace name: `copy mykeyspacename.users (uid, ...`

Comment: @Bryceatnetwork23 the confusing thing is that i definitely in the keyspace that contains users table. The input file is in a file of hadoop cluster. Do i need to copy it to my local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, i figure it out myself. i don't move the file to local. its originally on a hadoop cluster. then i works using

```
copy users (uid, gender, age, occu, zip) from 'users.dat' with delimiter = ':';
```

hope this help others.